# How can I move multiple UIImage views around a view controller?

Tags: uiimageview, touch, move, uipangesturerecognizer

How can I move multiple UIImage views around a view controller?

I have managed to use this code;

```
-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{
    printf("touch began --------- |n");


}


-(void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{
    printf("touch moved --------- |n");


    UITouch *myTouch = [touches anyObject];
    startPoint = [myTouch locationInView:self.view];



    ball.center = CGPointMake(startPoint.x, startPoint.y);

    }


-(void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{
    printf("touch end --------- |n");

    }
```

This code above has made it so that I can move one UIImage view around with touch, however, I want to be able to move 100's around. This code also, currently, when you move your finger around an area of the screen the image jumps to your finger.

Is this the best way to do it? Or is a pan gesture better?

Please help me make it so I can move multiple images around my view controller with touch and if you use the code above, please stop the image from jumping!

Please help!

.H FILE FOR ANSWER REFERRAL;

```
@interface CMViewController : UIViewController {
    CGPoint startPoint;


}


@property CGPoint startPoint;

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *smyImageView;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *smyImageView1;





@end
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use below. I used this for multiple images moving on screen. It's working for me.

```
UIPanGestureRecognizer *span=[[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc]initWithTarget:self action:@selector(onsPan:)];

 [smyImageView addGestureRecognizer:span];

   UIPanGestureRecognizer *span1=[[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc]initWithTarget:self action:@selector(onsPan1:)];

   [smyImageView1 addGestureRecognizer:span1];
```

Moving (Pan):

```
- (void)onsPan:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)recognizer {

   CGPoint translation = [recognizer translationInView:self.view];
    recognizer.view.center = CGPointMake(recognizer.view.center.x + translation.x,
                                         recognizer.view.center.y + translation.y);
    [recognizer setTranslation:CGPointMake(0, 0) inView:self.view];

}

- (void)onsPan1:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)recognizer {

    CGPoint translation = [recognizer translationInView:self.view];
    recognizer.view.center = CGPointMake(recognizer.view.center.x + translation.x,
                                         recognizer.view.center.y + translation.y);
    [recognizer setTranslation:CGPointMake(0, 0) inView:self.view];

}
```

Comment: Am I correct in thinking I would just add "span2, span3" and so on for each image view?

Comment: I will! I will be implementing it in about 7 hours.

Comment: Am I putting this in the viewDidLoad?

Comment: Hello, I have implemented this in the viewDidLoad and Xcode has accepted the code, I run the app and I can't move the UIViews, if this worked for you, I must be able to het it working. Maybe my .h is incorrect?  I have updated my code in my question with my .h

Comment: why did you use this line - (IBAction)onsPan:(id)sender;? It makes no sense.

Comment: Sorry I posted the wrong code from a previous attempt, updating now.

Answer (score 0):

This will teach you everything you need to know for what you want to do.

http://www.raywenderlich.com/44270/sprite-kit-tutorial-how-to-drag-and-drop-sprites

This is another [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8640103/touch-and-drag-an-image-around-the-screen) that may help you

Comment: Thanks so much for your answer! I haven't used the Spritekit game project set up before.  Can you use storyboards within a Spritekit game or will I have to work completely programmatically? I will be at my mac tonight and going through this great link you have sent.

Comment: You can use the storyboard for some parts, I only use it for creating setting screens etc. But generally sprite kit is code. The tutorial will get you started. If you want just iOS, you could use the same principle, just set the image views you want to move with a tag. Let me know how u go.

Comment: I will Smick! I will vote up the answer as soon as I have tried it, don't worry! Thank you for your reply.

Comment: This was a great tutorial to follow, however, how do I choose where the images are placed within the view controller when it is built? I'm adding easily 100 images that all need to be movable, is their anyway I can reference the images on a storyboard? This would make things a heck of a lot easier.

Comment: Is there no way to make the code above reference more than one image?

Comment: give each a tag, then move all images with that tag.

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm a novice, could you show me some code for this? Or perhaps a link so I could read up on it? Thanks again.